# Getting SQL server to recognise a date column

Tags: sql-server, date, alias

I am trying to get a count of IDS on a orders table for yesterday (not hardcode) where the date in the table corresponds to when the order was placed.

My table looks like this

```
orders (
order_id INT PRIMARY KEY
, user_id INT
, date_created DATE
, order_value FLOAT
, city_id INT
)
```

I have used this code to get todays date in the table -

```
Select *,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as Today
From orders
```

This works fine but when I try attempt a where clause below this

```
Select *,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as Today
From orders
where Today -1 = date_created;
```

I receive this error "Invalid column name 'Today'"
So my question is simply how can I get this table to recognise the the date I added as a new column and allow me to perform work on it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dan shows a much smoother way to convert `GETDATE()` (well, any date, really) to date: `CONVERT(date, GETDATE())`. Also I strongly recommend avoiding shorthand (you type `dd`; why not just type `day`?) and `Today-1` (this will break with newer date/time types). See [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) and [this](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/).

Comment: Thanks for the links!! Dans answer does work perfectly but I wanted a count and just that and with Dans method I have two column headings, one with the count and the other todays date.  I thought this might be confusing for someone who wasnt familar with the script.  I am studying both answers as I am sure will be needed again in future.

Comment: No worries, I wasn't trying to suggest one answer over another, just acknowledging that Dan also mentioned convert to date vs. dateadd/datediff hackiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because of the way queries are [logically processed](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/logical-query-processing/).

You need to either use a common table expression:

```
WITH c
    AS
     (
         SELECT *, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS Today
         FROM   orders
     )
SELECT *
FROM   c
WHERE  c.Today - 1 = date_created;
```

Or you could use a derived table.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (   SELECT *, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS Today
           FROM   orders ) AS c
WHERE  c.Today - 1 = date_created;
```

Neither one is "better".

Answer (score 5):

> I receive this error "Invalid column name 'Today'"

You can't reference the `Today` expression in the `WHERE` clause because the `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause according to the [logical order of query processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql).

Since your desired type is `date`, it would be better to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` rather than the `DATEADD...DATEDIFF` ugliness (common before SQL Server 2008 introduced the `date` datatype). Also, you need to use `DATEADD` to calculate yesterday's date instead of a subtraction operator.

The example below uses these techniques to get the orders from yesterday:

```
SELECT
      order_id
    , user_id
    , date_created
    , order_value
    , city_id
    , CAST(GETDATE() AS date) as Today
FROM dbo.orders
WHERE DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) = date_created;
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated you're not able to use a calculation done in the SELECT clause in the WHERE clause due to the order of operations.

However, a nifty workaround I use from time to time is to do some calculations within a CROSS APPLY, and then those can be referenced in SELECT and WHERE. It is a helpful technique to avoid repeating code.

```
SELECT 
    A.*,
    S1.Today
FROM orders A
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT
            CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) Today
    ) S1
WHERE   DATEADD(DAY, -1, S1.Today) = A.date_created;
```